# How to know the tire pressure of my car?

Tags: tires, nissan, tire-pressure

I am a new car owner (Nissan Note manufactured in 2016) and I am learning how to do basic maintenance on my car instead of going to the shop which is expensive. I want to check the tire pressure on my own but I have a problem: how do I find out the proper tire pressure for my car?

I have read every page of the owner's manual and it does not say anything. I also know that it is not in the markings on the tire, which indicates dimensions and speed rating.

Comment: The max pressure should be shown on the tyre...

Comment: Sharing the make, model and year of your car can help us give a more specific answer. Tire size and brand will help too, in case they are not OEM.

Comment: @SolarMike - While the ***max pressure*** is shown on the tire, you should always follow the vehicle manufacturer's recommendations. If you don't, problems can arise with the car which could cause safety concerns.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I only made the comment as the OP said "it is not in the markings on the tire" which is incorrect as the max pressure is ALWAYS given. I agree that the OP should find the correct pressures for the year, model and make of their car AND make sure they adjust the pressures according to what loads are being carried as that will also make a difference.

Comment: @SolarMike - You are correct. It just seemed you were instructing the OP to use the markings on the side of the tire to adjust tire pressure.

Comment: Let your conscience be your guide ; There is no right or wrong answer. I usually check the pressure which is always on my tires and put in close to the max . Then ,later, look for high or low pressure wear on the tread.

Comment: Once had new tires marked 32 psi max. I put in 32, drove on the highway for awhile and the checked pressure . the pressure pinned my gage at 50 psi. Also the owners manual said put in 22 psi ( an Imperial, I never owned another Chrysler product.)

Comment: @CharlieRB the car is a Nissan Note manufactured in 2016. But I'm wondering, how do you guys find out? I know I can always ask the shop but I'd have to ask for every model. I want to know how one finds out / deduce the tire pressure.

Comment: How do we find out what? Paulster has told you where we would look. The owners manual I found online does not give pressures, rather it states "**The Tire and Loading Information label is affixed to the driver side center pillar**" in section 8 for Maintenance and Do-It-Yourself. If that isn't answering your question, you need to ask it a different way.

Comment: In the US those stickers are actually legally required. If you bought the car new and cant find it maybe go to the dealer and find out why you don't have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually in the driver's side door jam there's a sticker which looks something like this:

[image]

It gives you what the tire pressure should be and load ratings for your vehicle (usually). If it isn't in the driver's door jam, look around at the other door jams. It should be there somewhere.

Comment: @Paulster2 is right, it will be posted. Other locations may be the fuel door, glove compartment. Look around.

Comment: You should also adjust, according to the manufacturer's information, the front and rear tyre pressures according to the number of occupants, the load being carried etc.